# Identifying Currently Running Process

Tags: vb.net

I need to identify the currently running Excel process id so I can compare it to other Excel process id's so that I can delete the other non-current Excel processes.  Here is what I have, but none of the process ids = current id.  What am I doing wrong?

`Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Int32`

```
Private Sub CheckMemory()
    Dim process As Process
    Dim xlProcessCount = process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL").Count()
    Dim curProc As IntPtr = GetCurrentProcessId()
    Dim currentProcess As Process = process.GetProcessById(curProc)


    If xlProcessCount > 1 Then
        '            MsgBox("There are " + xlProcessCount + "Excel processes running", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        'Associate the current active "Excel.exe" process with this application instance 
        'and delete the other running processes

        Dim current = process.GetCurrentProcess()
        For Each process In process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
            If process.Id <> currentProcess.Id Then
                MsgBox("Deleting a previous running Excel process", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

                process.Kill()

                '                    releaseObject(xlApp)
                '                    releaseObject(xlWb)
                '                    releaseObject(xlWs)

            End If
        Next

    End If
```

Comment: It seems like we've come in half way through where things have already gone wrong and you're spawning multiple Excel processes and leaking them, and you've decided that the right way to fix it is to let the leak continue but try to mop it up continuously. If that's not the case, can you explain what the "current active" excel instance is, why it's special, and generally what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Is your current code running in Excel via VSTO or something similar?

Comment: "Currently running" has no meaning, all of these copies of excel.exe are just as currently running.  COM doesn't provide a mechanism to identify the server.  GetCurrentProcessId() certainly won't work, that's your process and never Excel.  Writing code like this is a band-aid for another problem.  Now you got two problems.

Comment: Damien...your sort of right.  I've noticed situations where the app can spawn multiple processes if the app is not closed correctly or some other unchecked exception causes it. Things have not already gone wrong, but I'm trying to prevent memory leaks from happening by deleting non-current Excel processes, which may or may not be the best way to do this.  I probably need to prevent the memory leaks from occurring in the first place.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on how to approach this.

Comment: shf301: I'm running VS2010

Comment: Well what this app does is pull data via web services into the dataviewgrid.  From there, I have a process to open and populate an Excel spreadsheet with the data.

Comment: I can when the process starts in the task manager.  What I'm doing is opening additional Excel apps so I can have more than one process running.  I'm trying to identify which Excel process my app has started.

Comment: I can see when the process starts in the task manager (I should say).

Comment: You can try keeping track of the multiple instances of Excel in your application. Use `ReleaseComObject` to kill them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question your code "doesn't work" because your process is not an Excel process.  The process ID returned by `GetCurrentProcessId()` is the ID for your EXE which is not Excel.  All of the Excel instances (even the one launched by your application) are different processes, so their process ID's will never match your process's ID.

Now to answer your problem - what you need to do is to ensure that you are cleaning up your Excel instances correctly.

The best way to do that is to not automate Excel at all, but to instead use a library that can create Excel files.  See the answers to this question for some examples: [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

If for some reason you need to use Excel you will have to ensure that you clean up every single object that the Excel application returns.  The general rules for that are:

1. Never use more than `.` in a call - you will need to store a reference to every object returned by Excel.
2. Use `Marhsal.ReleaseObject` to manually release all of the Excel COM objects.

See this question [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects) for more details.

Comment: Ok, thanks shf301... I'm looking at the link and the links spawned from that link.  I think I may have a solution.